# VS JavaScript IntelliSense not working as expected

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense, code-completion

I want IntelliSense to work as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874692.aspx).

Unfortunately, what I get is this:
[image]

As you can see, there are several differences.

- false icon
- false member info
- no quick info
- thousands of other list entries, I don´t need

This is a simple ASP.NET empty webproject in VS 2015. I have checked the options under Text-Editor -> JavaScript, which seems to be correctly.

Comment: Are you running resharper?  I seem to recall having loads of issues with JS intellisense until I disabled resharper in .js files to some degree.

Comment: Having just reverted the setting, I'm almost certain you're running resharper - I see the behaviour switching between what you're seeing and what the blog post is saying.  If you can confirm, I'll post an answer.

Comment: yes, i am running resharper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably being caused by ReSharper - I've actually had a better experience by disabling the ReShaper intellisense for JavaScript and letting it fall back to using Visual Studio.

To do so, go to:

- ReSharper->Options
- Expand the Intellisense group under Environment, choose General
- Select "Custom IntelliSense"
- Select Visual Studio in the drop down on the right for JavaScript

I've personally left all others set to ReSharper.

By toggling this setting between the two choices, I switch between seeing what you're describing in the question and what the blog post you linked to describes.

Comment: Solution worked. I am wondering if the javascript language service in vs does not support quickinfo "on demand". Means that it only shows quickinfo when typing a dot and not while hovering over. Also, the button show quickinfo in the toolbar is grayed out.